# Scrolling to the end of a AnimatedList

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a scrollable `AnimatedList` and I want whenever a new item is added to the end of the list, it would scroll to the end.

I try to apply this code form `ListView` but it doesn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<String> list = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"];
  final ScrollController _listScrollController = new ScrollController();
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AnimatedList(
          key: _listKey,
          controller: _listScrollController,
          initialItemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: Container(
                width: itemSize,
                height: itemSize,
                child: Text(list[index]),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _addNewItem),
    );
  }

  _addNewItem() {
    list.add(list.length.toString());
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(
      list.length - 1,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    _listScrollController.animateTo(
      _listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, // wrong value (this value is before add new item)
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  }
}
```

So I need to change the scroll code a little bit.

```
const double itemSize = 40.0;

_listScrollController.animateTo(
   _listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent + itemSize,
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
   curve: Curves.ease,
);
```

But it need itemSize to hardcode(itemSize) or use BuildLayout, RenderBox to  determine new item size. Do you guys have any better solutions?

Answer (score 7):

The issue is you were animating the stuff before adding the item. You were taking a duration of 1s to add item, use this timer that will run after 1s.

```
Timer(
  Duration(milliseconds: 1100),
  () {
    _listScrollController.animateTo(
      _listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  },
);
```

---

Replace yours with mine.

```
_addNewItem() {
  list.add(list.length.toString());
  _listKey.currentState.insertItem(
    list.length - 1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  );

  Timer(
    Duration(milliseconds: 220),
    () {
      _listScrollController.animateTo(
        _listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This code not work. ```_listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent``` is value before list add new item. So I must hardcode new itemSize ```_listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent + itemSize```. Please read my question carefully again.

Comment: Use Timer the fade animation will be animated before scroll so we can miss fade animation.

Comment: I have seen that you don't accept answers, your original post was how to scroll to the end, I gave you the solution, it is working as expected. But now you are trying to figure out some nuance in the solution so that you have a reason/excuse not to accept and upvote it. It is against the spirit of Stackoverflow. Have a great day anyhow!

Comment: If It just about scrolls to end, why I must use Animated List in the first place, just refactor to ListView and everything will work as expected. I want AnimatedList scroll to end with a new item added animation happen in same time.
So I don't accept it. But I will upvote your answer.